# Error while asynchronously fetching Image metadata from Unsplash (Xcode Version 13.0 beta 3)

Tags: swift

I'm trying to update one of my packages (that didn't work perfectly) with the new concurrency features in Swift however I can't seem to handle the errors correctly in my function.

```
func getURL(apiURL: URL) async -> UnsplashData {
    do {
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: apiURL)
        return try JSONDecoder().decode(UnsplashData.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        print("Failed to fetch image")
        return UnsplashData(urls: Urls(raw: ""), links: UnsplashDataLinks(html: ""), user: User(name: ""))
    }
}
```

I get errors on the return statement in the catch block telling me to fix the error by adding `as! Decoder` to the strings and replace the argument labels with `from:` instead.

[image: Errors]

Here is the struct I use to decode the response from the API.

```swift
// MARK: - UnsplashData
struct UnsplashData: Codable {
    let id: String?
    let createdAt, updatedAt, promotedAt: Date?
    let width, height: Int?
    let color, blurHash: String?
    let unsplashDataDescription: String?
    let altDescription: String?
    let urls: Urls?
    let links: UnsplashDataLinks?
    let categories: [String]?
    let likes: Int?
    let likedByUser: Bool?
    let currentUserCollections: [String]?
    let sponsorship: JSONNull?
    let user: User?
    let exif: Exif?
    let location: Location?
    let views, downloads: Int?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case createdAt = "created_at"
        case updatedAt = "updated_at"
        case promotedAt = "promoted_at"
        case width, height, color
        case blurHash = "blur_hash"
        case unsplashDataDescription = "description"
        case altDescription = "alt_description"
        case urls, links, categories, likes
        case likedByUser = "liked_by_user"
        case currentUserCollections = "current_user_collections"
        case sponsorship, user, exif, location, views, downloads
    }
}

// MARK: - Exif
struct Exif: Codable {
    let make, model, exposureTime, aperture: String?
    let focalLength: String?
    let iso: Int?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case make, model
        case exposureTime = "exposure_time"
        case aperture
        case focalLength = "focal_length"
        case iso
    }
}

// MARK: - UnsplashDataLinks
struct UnsplashDataLinks: Codable {
    let linksSelf, html, download, downloadLocation: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case linksSelf = "self"
        case html, download
        case downloadLocation = "download_location"
    }
}

// MARK: - Location
struct Location: Codable {
    let title, name, city, country: String?
    let position: Position?
}

// MARK: - Position
struct Position: Codable {
    let latitude, longitude: Double?
}

// MARK: - Urls
struct Urls: Codable {
    let raw, full, regular, small: String?
    let thumb: String?
}

// MARK: - User
struct User: Codable {
    let id: String?
    let updatedAt: Date?
    let username, name, firstName, lastName: String?
    let twitterUsername: String?
    let portfolioURL: String?
    let bio: String?
    let location: String?
    let links: UserLinks?
    let profileImage: ProfileImage?
    let instagramUsername: String?
    let totalCollections, totalLikes, totalPhotos: Int?
    let acceptedTos: Bool?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case updatedAt = "updated_at"
        case username, name
        case firstName = "first_name"
        case lastName = "last_name"
        case twitterUsername = "twitter_username"
        case portfolioURL = "portfolio_url"
        case bio, location, links
        case profileImage = "profile_image"
        case instagramUsername = "instagram_username"
        case totalCollections = "total_collections"
        case totalLikes = "total_likes"
        case totalPhotos = "total_photos"
        case acceptedTos = "accepted_tos"
    }
}

// MARK: - UserLinks
struct UserLinks: Codable {
    let linksSelf, html, photos, likes: String?
    let portfolio, following, followers: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case linksSelf = "self"
        case html, photos, likes, portfolio, following, followers
    }
}

// MARK: - ProfileImage
struct ProfileImage: Codable {
    let small, medium, large: String?
}

// MARK: - Encode/decode helpers

class JSONNull: Codable, Hashable {

    public static func == (lhs: JSONNull, rhs: JSONNull) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    public var hashValue: Int {
        return 0
    }

    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        // No-op
    }

    public init() {}

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if !container.decodeNil() {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(JSONNull.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for JSONNull"))
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encodeNil()
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have nothing to return, don't return a fake object; throw.

Answer (score 1):

You need to properly initialise the parameters:

```
return UnsplashData(
    urls: Urls(raw: "", full: nil, regular: nil, small: nil, thumb: nil), 
    links: ..., 
    user: ...)
```

For your convenience you may refactor your `Urls`, `UnsplashDataLinks` and `User` struct which take an initialiser with default parameters.